# VBA Excel action when closing workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible automatically let Excel do an action when someone closes the file?

Situation:
I have an Excel file which is also used by several other people. This file publishes a mhtml file whens saving. This mhtml file will be saved with the date of yesterday like "Dashboard 2015-01-12". The seen data in the mhtml file has to contain the date related to the file name. The data seen depends on a single cell in this excel file, G2.

I want the Excel file to do this: 
change a single cell (G2) into the date of yesterday. Then save it. Then close it.

I want this action to be done:
when someone is closing the file.

Code I have so far:

```
Sub sbWriteCellWhenClosing()

Workbooks("BOOK1.XLS").Close SaveChanges:=True
Range("G2") = Format(Now - 2, dd - mm - yy)

End Sub
```

Edit:

Will this do the job?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  Range("G2") = Format(Now - 1, dd - mm - yy)
   ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Try looking into `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)`

Comment: I guess that will do. Am I supposed to close this question now?

Comment: You don't have to, it's probably been flagged, and if it's viewed as being a duplicate, it will get closed.  If someone wants to write up a formal answer, you can select it or write your own answer.  Keep in mind, you don't want a high ratio of deleted questions.  If you delete too many of your own questions, there can be a temporary question ban.  So I'd leave it to the moderators to decide in this case.  It's not cut and dry anyway.  you are using the same event, but with different requirements.  If you needed help specifically with the sub that gets called, I'd LEAVE it OPEN.

Comment: You had `Now - 2`, but yesterday would be `now - 1` also.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**This is using the Workbook code:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call sbWriteCellWhenClosing
End Sub
```

**In a separate Module:**

```
Sub sbWriteCellWhenClosing()

    ActiveSheet.Range("G2") = Format(Now - 1, "dd-mm-yy")   '-1 for yesterday
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Workbook.BeforeClose` event :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194765%28v=office.15%29.aspx

to do that in project window in VBA editor you have to use ThisWorkbook and place your code there. Your code will work only for workbooks modified in this way.