# prevent excel from closing if a cell in a particular column is empty and cell adjacent to it is filled

Tags: excel, vba

I guess this needs a VB Macro. I need to know how to do this. I have an excel sheet,lets say with four columns - NAME, AGE, GENDER and BIRTHDAY. Suppose I want to ensure that the AGE column is always filled for all the records and is always positive and above zero. Number of records in the file are not fixed so file can have 5 rows or 500 rows. I need to make sure that if any of the columns NAME, GENDER or BIRTHDAY is filled in a row and AGE is blank, 0 or negative then excel should prevent the user from closing the file.

Comment: You should post the code you already tried. Also, it is quite annoying for users who experience this application behaviour. Imagine I had a genuine reason to close the file, but now I've got some nagging spreadsheet telling me to fill out the form...

Comment: I have not tried any code yet, I am searching for a viable code as I am not very good in VB. Also the users can just delete the whole record and close the file. It is imperative that users should not save any record without adding age. Its a precaution so that mandatory fields are filled - just like mandatory fields on a web form.

Comment: If column `Birthday` is filled, surely you can infer `Age` - so one less thing to worry about?

Comment: Actually this is just an example. My actual excel sheet has many more columns and one happens to be mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

you can hack this solution a little to suit your needs

VBA Excel action when closing workbook

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27923799/6868389

Answer (score 0):

Since the particular details of your question are so vague i can propose a solution to the closing part. The individual conditions you will have to add based on what exactly you have in the file and want but you can add them in between to set MyValidations to 1. As mentioned above this is based on Workbook_BeforeClose event. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194765.aspx

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If MyValidations = 1 Then
        Cancel = False
    Else
        MsgBox "Nope'"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```